# Customise one or more Columns (to also map future updates from worksheet 1) in all worksheets

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007

I have a workbook with 6 different worksheets but I want some columns to stay the same for all worksheets (and map any changes I may make to column A in Worksheet 1 - so that I don't have to manually make the required changes to all worksheets) - how do I do this please?

Comment: Welcome to superuser. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

Focussing on “*so that I don't have to manually make the required changes to all worksheets*” (because I don’t fully understand your question): If you have six sheets that are, in part, the same and wish to make one change apply to all six then group the six sheets (either select them manually with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + left click on each tab, or select the range with <kbd>Shift</kbd>+left click on first and last in the range.)

Remember to deselect the grouping before working elsewhere on the sheets however. The Title bar should show whether or not grouping is in effect and the background of the tabs changes colour.

If you want exact copies of Sheet1 for part of the array, make the cells on Sheets2-6 refer to the corresponding Sheet1 entry.